# im trying to make a pacman with Phaser in js. how can i make borders for the places you can't go?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so it can't go in there

[image: 1]

tried looking on websites but could not find anything

Comment: Check out this [official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/grid-movement) from the official website.

Comment: Actullay [these examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/tilemap/collision) all might be even better, showing collisions